# Metadata Sometimes Returns Completely Incorrect Date Created

Tags: c#, image, metadata

I am getting the date that a picture was created in C#.  This is the method that I am using.

```
foreach (PropertyItem propItem in image.PropertyItems)
{
    if (propItem.Id == 0x0132)
    {
        date = (new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetString(propItem.Value));
        MessageBox.Show("The picture " + file + " was taken at " + date);
        image.Dispose();
        date = date.Substring(0, 4);
        monthstring = getPath + "\\" + date;
        if (!Directory.Exists(monthstring))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(monthstring);
        }
        File.Move(file, monthstring + "\\" + filetype);
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
}
```

Now, this method works- sometimes.  Some of the time, it returns the completely incorrect date!  Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?  Sometimes it says it was taken today, when it was taken in 2005.  Sometimes it gives me the wrong month, too.  Mostly it's the year that's screwed up.

Comment: I don't think you are handling the date particularly well but I don't see any reason why the code would return a different year. Have you confirmed that the metadata does not in fact read the date returned by your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get the Date Created property 
System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem propertyItem = image.GetPropertyItem( 0x132 ); 
if( propItem != null ) 
{ 
  // Extract the property value as a String. 
  System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
  string text = encoding.GetString(propertyItem.Value, 0, propertyItem.Len - 1 ); 

  // Parse the date and time. 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; 
  DateTime dateCreated = DateTime.ParseExact( text, "yyyy:MM:d H:m:s", provider ); 
}
```

Original Answers:

[“Date Taken” not showing up in Image PropertyItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14308382/1629490)

[How can I find out when a picture was actually taken in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7713780/1629490)