# Slow performance when extracting Exif data using metadata-extractor

Tags: c#, .net, metadata-extractor

I have a fairly simple task - from a collection of images I need to extract the Creation Date, the Last Modified Date and the Picture Taken Date and write them to a text file. For the Picture Taken Date, I am using [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet).

This is some sample code,

```
    List<FileInfo> fileList = Utils.FileList(targetPath, true);
    foreach (FileInfo fi in fileList)
    {
        string dateTime = "";
        try
        {
            var metadatadir = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(fi.FullName);
            var subIfdDirectory = metadatadir.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
            dateTime = subIfdDirectory?.GetDescription(ExifDirectoryBase.TagDateTimeOriginal);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        DateTime creationDate = File.GetCreationTime(fi.FullName);
        DateTime modifiedDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(fi.FullName);
        string outputLine = "Filename " + fi.Name + "\t Creation Time: " + creationDate +
            "\t Modified Time: " + modifiedDate + "\t" + "Exif Time: " + dateTime + "\n";
        File.AppendAllText(targetFile, outputLine);
        fileCount++;
    }
```

I wrap a `Stopwatch` object around this block to measure performance and this is the result I get,

> Processed 2244 files in 440218ms.

If I comment out the Exif code (the `try-catch` block) I get,

> Processed 2244 files in 116928ms.

Am I using the library incorrectly? Is there a faster way of pulling the data out?

**EDIT** Based on feedback I have switched to using `StreamWriter` as below,

```
using (StreamWriter tFile = File.AppendText(targetFile))
{
    // Code
    tFile.WriteLine(outputLine);
}
```

Based on this latest change the time taken has been cut in half with the Exif code,

> Processed 2244 files in 212278ms.

Comment: Your code is identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839380/150605) (with the exception of `subIfdDirectory?.GetDescription()` vs. `subIfdDirectory?.GetDateTime()`) from someone claiming to be the author of that very library and touting its performance compared to `System.Drawing.Image`, so presumably that is the correct usage.  It does provide an alternative method if you know the input format and can restrict the requested metadata.

Comment: The code is based off a sample on GitHub for this library, and that specifies using the `metadata-extractor` tag when posting on StackOverflow. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Performance in your case is likely down to I/O. Now the code you're using pulls out all metadata types for all file formats. If you only want, day, Exif for JPEG files, itmay be possible to improve performance.

Comment: Instead of calling File.AppendAllText in the loop, create a stream writer and spend to that, so that you only open and close the output file once rather than once per input file. It will allow more buffering too.

Comment: I'm on my phone but can find you some code soon if you explain your use case in more detail.

Comment: Drew, thanks for the suggestion. Using `StreamWriter` has made a substantial improvement to the performance time. My use case is that I have a large library of files littered across many folders that have been backed up over the years from cameras, phones, etc. I want to organise them all by folders ordered by the exposure date. Any other optimisations you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Based on following comments from [Drew Noakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24874/drew-noakes),

> Performance in your case is likely down to I/O. Now the code you're
>   using pulls out all metadata types for all file formats. If you only
>   want, day, Exif for JPEG files, itmay be possible to improve
>   performance
>
> Instead of calling
>   `File.AppendAllText` in the loop, create a `StreamWriter` and spend to
>   that, so that you only open and close the output file once rather than
>   once per input file. It will allow more buffering too.

I have done exactly this and performance speed has doubled, which is good enough for my purposes. See edit in the original post.